# Input data of variable length - two scenarios

Tags: text, mlp, features

I'm trying to figure out how I could train a neural network with inputs that have variable length. This issue comes up in the following 2 scenarios I'm trying to solve.

Scenario 1:
I have a long list of running distances for various runners which looks something like has 3 columns: runner, date, distance.
Obviously some runners have a lot of entries and others don't. I'm trying to make predictions on the number of miles a given runner will run next. So I'm guessing i need to transform my data to have one line per runner, which gives me variable length features. How can I deal with this in a ML application?

Scenario 2:
I'd like to take various strings ("teststring", "P@ssword", "NotAPassword123", etc...) and classify it as a password or not. I guess i'm trying to figure out how to a) convert strings to numbers to train on and b) how to deal with the fact that they have variable length.

Thanks for reading this far...

Answer (score 1):

For scenario 1, if you have enough data for each runner, you could build separate models for them otherwise you can add runner as a categorical variable by one hot encoding your runners and then trying out your model.
For scenario 2, you can create fixed sized vectors for each string by handcrafting features, such as count of consonants, count of vowels, presence of special characters, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1: It seems like you're dealing with columns that may lack data. You have a few options for assigning values to rows that have no information in certain columns, and each have advantages and drawbacks that depend on your dataset. An example is to assign the mean or median of that column for `NaN` entries, which has the drawback of reducing variance in your data. [Here's an article on the topic](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-handle-missing-data-8646b18db0d4) that should help you.

Scenario 2: For part "b", a common approach is to simply find a length that should be "big enough" and adding [padding](https://machinelearningmastery.com/data-preparation-variable-length-input-sequences-sequence-prediction/) to sequences (or, in your case, strings) which are "too short". For part "a", a very simple approach would be to apply [bag of words](https://machinelearningmastery.com/gentle-introduction-bag-words-model/) at a character level. Alternatively, you could experiment with trainin a [character embedding model](https://github.com/karpathy/char-rnn) on your password text; such models would create a vectorized representation of your text that you can feed to whatever model you use for password classification!